# Ninject Kernel Injection of a provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm trying to use the `[Inject]` attribute on a `BasicRoleProvider : RoleProvider` provider.

In my provider, I did:

```
public class BasicRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    [Inject]
    private IAuthenticationService authenticationService;
    /*Other stuff here*/
}
```

My Global.asax.cs file is as follows:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    /* Other stuff here */
    #region Inversion of Control

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return Container;
    }

    static IKernel _container;
    public static IKernel Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (_container == null)
            {
                _container = new StandardKernel(new SiteModule());
            }
            return _container;
        }
    }

    internal class SiteModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            //Set up ninject bindings here.
            Bind<IAuthenticationService>().To<AuthenticationService>();

            this.Kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);

        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Whenever a method in the `BasicRoleProvider` gets executed and is using the `authenticationService`, its null. I think my problem lies in the **Global.ascx.cs** file. Am I doing the injection right?

Comment: What is Roles.Provider? Is it your own class, Post the code where you're initializing an instance of BasicRolerProvider.

Comment: @Yads `Roles.Provider` is an asp.net provider class. There are others such as `Membership.Provider`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible that you are using Ninject in an unsupported way.

From https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Changes-in-Ninject-2

> **Things that were in Ninject 1.x that are not in Ninject 2:**
>
> Field injection: This is a bad
>   practice, and has been cut for
>   minimization.

Because you tagged your question MVC 3, I assume you are linking to Ninject 2. As far as I know, Ninject 1 in an MVC 3 app would be a dead end.

The `Inject` attribute still exists, and fields must still be a valid target for it, which is why you do not get a compile time error.

But Ninject 2 will happily ignore that `Inject` attribute on the fields, which is why it is null for you.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you have any idea how to do DI on a provider?

Comment: ctor injection, but I'm not sure off-hand what hook, if any, is available to get control of the Provider's instantiaion.

Comment: @DVark, try using Property injection.

Comment: he's using field injection. Also property injection is supported in NInject 2. I've used it.